Sierpinski space does not induce a condensed set.
I've been reading https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf and I've got stuck in Warning 2.14.

The problem are nonseparated spaces like
the Sierpinski space $X = \{s, η\}$, where $\{η\}$ is open but $\{s\}$ is not. Indeed, then $\underline{X}$ sends any
extremally disconnected set $S$ to the set of all closed subsets of $S$, and this functor is not the left
Kan extension of its restriction to $κ$-small extremally disconnected sets for any $κ$ (otherwise any closed subset $Z ⊂ S$ of an extremally disconnected set $S$ would be an intersection of $κ$ clopen
subsets of $S$ for some cardinal $κ$ independent of $S$ and $Z$).

As far as I understand, the left Kan extension of restriction is given by some colimit.
But I don't know why the following holds if $\underline{X}$ is a condensed set.

"otherwise any closed subset $Z ⊂ S$ of an extremally disconnected set $S$ would be an intersection of $κ$ clopen
subsets of $S$ for some cardinal $κ$ independent of $S$ and $Z$."

